# Running Firebase Firestore transactions including a loop in async React Native function

Tags: javascript, react-native, transactions, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am trying to get a queue of userIds; then, add the first 2 userIds to an array by sequentially getting their data and checking if they meet the criteria.

The function below gives me 6 alerts intended for debug suggesting the transaction keeps re-running. Without the debug alerts the error message is 'firestore/invalid-argument'. Debugging confirmed it's creating the array (toArray) correctly.

When I comment out the for loop and just push a userId into the array (toArray) the transaction runs perfectly. You can see these efforts in the code below. I think the **await transaction.get() in the loop** is causing the issue but don't know how to fix it.

Any expertise in the field or solution ideas would help me greatly. I also looked for online resources but couldn't quite find anything referring my situation. Thanks in advance.

```
  send = () => {
    const messagesRef = firebase.firestore().collection('messages');
    const messageStatsDoc = messagesRef.doc('--stats--');
    const messageRefDoc = messagesRef.doc();
    const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');

    const reach = 2;
    const { kindtag, message, currentUser } = this.state;

    if (kindtag == 'Select kindtag') {
      return alert("No kindtag selected");
    };

    const updateFunction = async transaction => {
      const mStatsDoc = await transaction.get(messageStatsDoc);
      let currentQueue = mStatsDoc.data().queue;

      let toArray = [];

      let outputs = ''; // for debug
      outputs = outputs + "," + currentQueue.length; // for debug

      for (let j = 0; j < currentQueue.length; j++) {
        let queuedUserID = currentQueue[j];
        if (queuedUserID != currentUser.uid) {
          let qUserRef = usersRef.doc(queuedUserID);
          let userQueued = await transaction.get(qUserRef);
          let kindtagReceive = userQueued.data().kindtagReceive;
          if (kindtagReceive.includes(kindtag)) {
            toArray.push(queuedUserID);
            if (toArray.length == reach) {
              break;
            };
          };
        };
        outputs = outputs + "," + j;
      };

      alert(outputs) // 6 alerts saying ",5,0,1,2" (or 2 seconds)

      //toArray.push('XR8pAKia5GZokNeTGGgtzwFY79g1') // comment out loop and uncomment this -> works
      //toArray.push('rbdIAi3TZngS2H79iElfjjMqiNl2')

      if (toArray.length) {
        // restructure queue
        toArray.forEach(async toUser => {
          await transaction.update(messageStatsDoc, {
            queue: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(toUser)
          });
          await transaction.update(messageStatsDoc, {
            queue: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(toUser)
          });
        });
                // create message
        await transaction.set(messageRefDoc, {
          from: currentUser.uid,
          to: toArray,
          kindtag: kindtag,
          message: message,
          upVote: 0,
          downVote: 0,
          messageTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          reports: []
        });
      } else {
        return alert("No match exists")
      };

      return reach;
    };

    firebase
      .firestore()
      .runTransaction(updateFunction)
      .then((reach) => {
        alert('Message sent to: ' + reach);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
  };
```